# Problem accessing a property within an object with variable name

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have some data that looks like this:

```
   [
          {
            teamName: '4',
            teamId: 6665,
            position: 1,
            points: 1000,
            posChange: 0,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          },
          {
            teamName: '3',
            teamId: 6667,
            position: 2,
            points: 735,
            posChange: 0,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          },
          {
            teamName: '1',
            teamId: 4608,
            position: 3,
            points: 561,
            posChange: 1,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          },
          {
            teamName: '2',
            teamId: 4494,
            position: 4,
            points: 535,
            posChange: -1,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          }
        ]
```

And I want to turn it into something like this:

```
[
   '21-5-2018': [ 
       {
            teamName: '4',
            teamId: 6665,
            position: 1,
            points: 1000,
            posChange: 0,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          },
          {
            teamName: '3',
            teamId: 6667,
            position: 2,
            points: 735,
            posChange: 0,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          },
          {
            teamName: '1',
            teamId: 4608,
            position: 3,
            points: 561,
            posChange: 1,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          },
          {
            teamName: '2',
            teamId: 4494,
            position: 4,
            points: 535,
            posChange: -1,
            rankDay: 21,
            rankMonth: 5,
            rankYear: 2018
          }
       ]
]
```

So I want to add each ranking instance to an object with the dates of the ranking. This is what I have so far:

```
// Reading the Json file with the data
let rawRankings = fs.readFileSync('rankings until 07-Sep-2020.json')
let rankings = JSON.parse(rawRankings);
let rankingsNew = [];
// Iterating through each element
rankings.forEach(function(value){
    // This is the name of the object that will group all the values for that date
    let newRankName = value.rankYear + "-" + value.rankMonth + "-" + value.rankDay;
    let length = rankingsNew.length;
    // Now I want to check if the object needs to be created or not, but this doesn't work, it always returns "undefined"
    if(typeof rankingsNew[newRankName] === 'undefined') {
        // Adding the object to the array since it doesn't exist
        rankingsNew.splice(length, 0, newRankName);
        // Trying to add this instance to the new object. Push doesn't work either
        rankingsNew.newRankName = value;
    }
    else {
        // Here I would only add the instance to the object since it already exists. Here is the push version for comparison
        rankingsNew.newRankName.push({
            "teamName" : value.teamName,
            "teamId": value.teamId,
            "position": value.position,
            "points": value.points,
            "posChange": value.posChange,
            "rankDay": value.rankDay,
            "rankMonth": value.rankMonth,
            "rankYear": value.rankYear, 
            "date": value.date
        })
    }
});
```

So I need to:

1- Check if that object exists (date of the rankings)

2- Be able to add an object to an empty JSON object if it doesn't exist yet (add the specified date as a new object that will have the rankings inside)

3- Then, once it is created / confirmed to exist, add the values of the instance to that object (each iteration that finds a ranking that belongs in each object should add it)

Thoughts?

Comment: so, the code does not work, yes?  The data array is not legal JSON.  `let newRankName` is creating the property who's value by definition is `undefined` because don't see a value being assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
you are just messing with objects/array structure.

```js
let rawRankings = fs.readFileSync('rankings until 07-Sep-2020.json')
let rankings = JSON.parse(rawRankings);

let rankingsNew = {};
// Iterating through each element
rankings.forEach(function(value) {
  // This is the name of the object that will group all the values for that date
  let newRankName = value.rankYear + "-" + value.rankMonth + "-" + value.rankDay;
  // Now I want to check if the object needs to be created or not, but this doesn't work, it always returns "undefined"
  if (!rankingsNew[newRankName]) {
    // Adding the object to the array since it doesn't exist

    // Trying to add this instance to the new object. Push doesn't work either
    rankingsNew[newRankName] = [value];

  } else {
    // Here I would only add the instance to the object since it already exists. Here is the push version for comparison
    rankingsNew[newRankName].push(value)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some fundamental errors in your code / data structure concept. You want to convert an array of objects to a Hashmap (or Record<string, object> in TypeScript), which will look like that:

```
{
  '21-5-2018': [ 
  //...
  ],
}
```

Obviously it is not possible with an array since arrays have a different data structure than what you want to get.

The solution would be as easy as that:

```
// Reading the Json file with the data
const rawRankings = fs.readFileSync('rankings until 07-Sep-2020.json')
const rankings = JSON.parse(rawRankings);
const rankingsNew = rankings.reduce((result, current) => {
  const newRankName = value.rankYear + "-" + value.rankMonth + "-" + value.rankDay;
  return {
    ...result,
    [newRankName]: [
      ...(result[newRankName] || []),
      current,
    ],
  };
}, {});
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. Tried your code and seems like it is only keeping 1 value for each date, while I have 30 different teams ranked for each date (like I showed in the example in the original post).